# Tkinter. Scale. Удаление

Tags: python, tkinter

Есть вопрос с тем как удалить видежт. Есть функция, которая при вызове создает виджет в определенном месте с помощью grid.

```
def select(): 
    i_row = var1.get()
    i_col = var2.get()
    scale = Scale(orient  = 'vertical', width = 250, state = "disable", sliderlength = 250, showvalue = 0)
    scale.grid(row = i_row, column = i_col, sticky = "ns")
```

Проблема состоит в том, что необходимо, чтобы при создании нового виджета уничтожался предыдущий. Как реализовать подобное? 
Тут видимо проблема в том, что виджет создается локально, потому что если использовать winfo exists(), то ошибка, так как переменная еще не объявлена.

Comment: Попробуйте `scale.grid_forget()`

Comment: Сохраняйте созданные виджеты например в глобальный словарь (ключ словаря - координаты движка в сетке) или просто в список, потом находите нужный виджет в словаре или списке, и удаляйте с помощью методов `grid_forget()` или `destroy()`.